# Could not find JSON file, File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, json, .net, maui, .net-maui

I have JSON file in /resources/raw but when im trying to load i have error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '/drinks.json'.'
Code:

```
string drinksJsonData = File.ReadAllText("drinks.json");
    var drinks = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<drinksclass>>(drinksJsonData);
    if(drinks != null)
    {
        foreach(var drink in drinks)
            {
            await DisplayAlert("ALERT", "WORKING", "OK");
            }
    }
```

I have `<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />` and `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />` in .csproj. I also tried change build settings but its still not working.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#bundled-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync` to achieve this function.

Please refer to the following code：

```
private async void OnReadClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
        var json = await LoadMauiAsset();
        await DisplayAlert("", json, "OK");
    }

    async Task<string> LoadMauiAsset()
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("fake.json");
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Note:please set the build action of your Jason to `MauiAsset`  .